# Rename control methods in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have just started coding in C#, and have been attempting to make a GUI application. I made a menu strip and wrote some code for one of the menu items. The method for clicking that menu item was automatically named "openToolStripMenuItem_Click".

In the properties I decided to change the name of the menu item from "open" to "save", but the method name remains the same, which is quite irritating. How do I get it to automatically adjust the method names when I rename a control?

Comment: The easiest way is to do a Find and Replace from `openToolStripMenuItem` to `saveToolStripMenuItem`, without using whole word match.

Comment: All right. I really expected that the method names would be adjusted automatically, seeing that all the code generated uses the control name for methods and such. I guess for the future I'll be sure to get the control name right before I try writing any code.

Comment: The `ControlName_EventName` thing is just a convention.  Programmers are not obligated to follow the convention, which is why it doesn't get renamed, but only code-genned when you first create the event stub.

Comment: Visual Studio has had a refactoring feature since VS 2005. Also, Resharper (a plugin for Visual Studio) does automatic renaming (refactoring) - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html

Comment: Don't use Find+Replace, that causes accidents.  Right-click the method name and use Refactor + Rename.

Comment: Pay for a productivity tool like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It will be worth it and will help you write better and more maintainable code.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'll skip, too many Resharper fans around here.  You can write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: The main reason why an event handler is _not_ renamed automatically when one of its associated controls is renamed, is because you can share a single event handler for multiple controls, and you would typically not want the IDE renaming these on you.  Search for _Sharing an Event Handler_ for additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not done automatically. A good way is to right-click the method name and use refactor + rename.